# Getting user input from JTextArea

Tags: java, oop, project, jtextarea

I'm trying to build a quiz program.

I decided that users enter their answers(numbers) into a JTextArea and the result will be shown on another JTextArea after a button click however I'm having troubles.

Here is partial of my code.

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit!");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    if(textArea_3.equals("1"))
                            {
                                textArea_1.setText("Correct!");
                            }




        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean -

```
    if(textArea_3.getText().equals("1"))
    {
        textArea_1.setText("Correct!");
        //your code
    }
```

and not

```
textArea_3.equals("1")
```

You cannot compare JTextArea instance with a String instance. You will always get false.

Answer (score 0):

`if(textArea_3.equals("1"))`

should be 
`if(textArea_3.getText().equals("1"))`